# Работа с данными AndroidWatch

Tags: java, android, android-wear

Мое приложение на android должно считывать пульс, пройденные шаги и т.д с умных часов. Как это реализовать/что почитать/где посмотреть по этой теме?

Comment: А гуглить не пробовали? Вот вопрос относящийся к теме пульска https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760344/how-to-read-heart-rate-from-android-wear 

По аналогии можно найти ответы на все остальные вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.
Могу посоветовать этот  [небольшой но очень полезный материал](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-09-17-tutorial-realtime-android-heart-rate-monitor-and-dashboard/)  для измерения пульса .Для измерения расстояния и пройденного пути можно использовать [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)